# ESP32 devkit v1 + LoRa rf96: spi configuration

Tags: esp32, lora, lorawan

I'm trying to connect the LoRa Tranciever RF96 to the ESP32 devkit v1.
In particular I need to understand how to connect the pins **nss**, **reset**, **dio0**, **dio1** and **dio2**.

[ESP32 pinout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7gso.jpg)

I would like to use [TheThingsNetwork library](https://www.thethingsnetwork.org/docs/devices/arduino/ide.html) on arduino framework with PlatformIO.

Does anyone know how i could configure the lora rf96 to send some simple strings to display on my The Things Network account?